# How to reduce boilerplate

Tags: javascript

I have store structure like this

```
/store
  /entities
    users.js
    sessions.js
```

All of my entities looks like this

```
import { FORM_ERROR } from 'react-final-form';
import { normalize, schema } from 'normalizr';

import { SCHEMA as USER_SHEMA } from './users';

export const SCHEMA = new schema.Entity(
  'sessions',
  { user: USER_SHEMA },
  { idAttribute: 'sessionGuid' },
);

export const CREATE_SESSION_REQUEST = 'CREATE_SESSION_REQUEST';
export const CREATE_SESSION_SUCCESS = 'CREATE_SESSION_SUCCESS';
export const CREATE_SESSION_FAILURE = 'CREATE_SESSION_FAILURE';

export const create = session => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  dispatch({ type: CREATE_SESSION_REQUEST });
  try {
    const { data } = await api.post('/sessions', session);
    const payload = normalize(data, SCHEMA);

    dispatch({ type: CREATE_SESSION_SUCCESS, payload });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_SESSION_FAILURE, payload: error, error: true });

    return { [FORM_ERROR]: error };
  }
  return null;
};

export const FETCH_ALL_SESSIONS_REQUEST = 'FETCH_ALL_SESSIONS_REQUEST';
export const FETCH_ALL_SESSIONS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_ALL_SESSIONS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_ALL_SESSIONS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_ALL_SESSIONS_FAILURE';

export const fetchAll = params => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_ALL_SESSIONS_REQUEST });
  try {
    const { data } = await api.get('/sessions', { params });
    const payload = normalize(data, [SCHEMA]);

    dispatch({ type: CREATE_SESSION_SUCCESS, payload });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_ALL_SESSIONS_FAILURE, payload: error, error: true });
  }
};

export const GET_ONE_SESSION_REQUEST = 'GET_ONE_SESSION_REQUEST';
export const GET_ONE_SESSION_SUCCESS = 'GET_ONE_SESSION_SUCCESS';
export const GET_ONE_SESSION_FAILURE = 'GET_ONE_SESSION_FAILURE';

export const fetchOne = sessionId => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  dispatch({ type: GET_ONE_SESSION_REQUEST });
  try {
    const { data } = await api.get(`/sessions/${sessionId}`);
    const payload = normalize(data, SCHEMA);

    dispatch({ type: GET_ONE_SESSION_SUCCESS, payload });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: GET_ONE_SESSION_FAILURE, payload: error, error: true });
  }
};

export const UPDATE_SESSION_REQUEST = 'UPDATE_SESSION_REQUEST';
export const UPDATE_SESSION_SUCCESS = 'UPDATE_SESSION_SUCCESS';
export const UPDATE_SESSION_FAILURE = 'UPDATE_SESSION_FAILURE';

export const update = (sessionId, session) => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  dispatch({ type: UPDATE_SESSION_REQUEST, meta: { id: sessionId } });
  try {
    await api.put(`/sessions/${sessionId}`, session);

    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_SESSION_SUCCESS, meta: { id: sessionId } });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_SESSION_FAILURE,
      error: true,
      payload: error,
      meta: { id: sessionId },
    });

    return { [FORM_ERROR]: error };
  }
  return null;
};

export const DESTROY_SESSION_REQUEST = 'DESTROY_SESSION_REQUEST';
export const DESTROY_SESSION_SUCCESS = 'DESTROY_SESSION_SUCCESS';
export const DESTROY_SESSION_FAILURE = 'DESTROY_SESSION_FAILURE';

export const destroy = sessionId => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  dispatch({ type: DESTROY_SESSION_REQUEST, meta: { id: sessionId } });
  try {
    await api.delete(`/sessions/${sessionId}`);

    dispatch({ type: DESTROY_SESSION_SUCCESS, meta: { id: sessionId } });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: DESTROY_SESSION_FAILURE,
      error: true,
      payload: error,
      meta: { id: sessionId },
    });
  }
};
```

I wanna use `import * as ns from './ns'` syntaxys in my components, so i export my actionTypes [like as constants](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux). In `users.js` the same code, but all the all words `session` are replaced with `users`. My project now has 12 entities, and when I replaced all the keywords in the 13th file, I remembered the DRY principle. But I did not find the right way to reduce the template code in such a way that would not change the imports.

```
import * as sessionsActions from 'store/modules/entities/sessions';
```

How to minimize the boilerplate by saving the current code?

Comment: Do you really need to export these constants if you want to use them generically only?

Comment: What build chain do you use? Could you actually create all these JS files from an actual *template*?

Comment: I think I need to export constants because they are used in reducers

Comment: I use webpack + babel for build my app